# Return object with Result T

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to return object values when I call methods. However, I also need to pass error messages along with these methods. As such I came up with an object like this:

```
public class ReturnObject
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Errors { get; set; }
    public dynamic Result { get; set; }
}
```

Now from my services, I can call this and return whatever I want along with any errors. However, the problem is that this is not type safe and I need cast the Result every time. So my goal is to make it type safe. Here is how I came up with that:

```
public class ReturnObject<T>
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Errors { get; set; }
    public T Result { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I return this object a lot, and as such, I Created a service which will return me the object. Trying to keep my code a bit dry. The service looks like this:

```
public class ResultService<T>
{
    public ReturnObject<T> GetGoodResult(T result)
    {
        return new ReturnObject { Success = true, Result = result };
    }


    public ReturnObject<T> GetGoodResult(T result, IEnumerable<string> errors)
    {
        return new ReturnObject { Success = false, Errors = errors, Result = result };
    }
}
```

So now lets says I have a service I want to use this from.

```
public class BookService
{
    private ResultService<book> _resultServiceBook = new ResultService<Book>();
    private ResultService<string> _resultServiceString = new ResultService<string>();

    public ReturnObject<Book> GetBook() 
    {
        return _resultServiceBook.GetGoodResult(new Book());
    }

    public ReturnObject<string> GetBookName(bookId)
    {
        return _resultServiceString.GetGoodResult(GetBookNameFromRepo(bookId));
    }
}
```

As you can see, for every type that I want to return, I have to create a new instance of ResultService with that type.  I can't seem to find a better way to accomplish this. I don't like that I have to create the same service multiple times like this to keep it type safe.

Just in case it is not clear what I mean when I say type safe, I mean that visual studio will catch type comparison while I'm still coding.

Comment: Since your `ResultService` class contains no state (i.e. it has no non-static fields) you can make the class and its methods `static`. That way you can just use it to create the results at the point where you return the result - you won't need to create a new instance of it seach time. Furthermore, you shouldn't need to specify the type at the point of call - the compiler can infer thet type (i.e. you can omit the `<T>` at the point of call). You will also need to remove the `<T>` from the class itself and just keep it on the methods.

Comment: You don't need a separate class for that, just add the static methods `ReturnObject<T>` (stupid name, just call it `Result<T>` or `QueryResult<T>`). Its neither bad nor anything, its a factory/convenience method to create the result, so its absolutely okay. Plus, this way you can encapsulate it better, with the ability to set private properties within the "factory" methods but preventing the same outside  (i.e. `public Success { get; private set; }`

Comment: Also see implementation of `IdentityResult` (from ASP.NET Core Identity): https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/2.1.2/src/Core/IdentityResult.cs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to specify the generic type at the class level, as you don't have any state that depends on the generic being specified at that level. Instead, just specify the generic arguments on the methods.

Also, there's no reason to have that as a service, you are looking for the Factory pattern:

```
public static class ResultFactory
{
    public static ReturnObject<T> GetGoodResult<T>(T result)
    {
        return new ReturnObject { Success = true, Result = result };
    }


    public static ReturnObject<T> GetGoodResult<T>(T result, IEnumerable<string> errors)
    {
        return new ReturnObject { Success = false, Errors = errors, Result = result };
    }
}
```

You can then use this as simply as:

```
var data = new SomeClass();
var result = ResultFactory.GetGoodResult(data);
```

And `result` will be a `ReturnObject<SomeClass>`.

Comment: I keep getting `Cannot resolve symbol T` error when I try to use your code.

Comment: For this to work, methods/class don't need to be static. What is the reason you have chosen to make them static?

Comment: @Bojan They don't need to be static, at all. When a class's only purpose is to have utility methods (just as the `ResultFactory` above), and it doesn't have any kind of state, it doesn't make sense to need to instantiate them. Also, `ResultFactory.GetGoodResult(data)` is much cleaner, IMO, than `new ResultFactory().GetGoodResult(data)` (what's that instance for?)

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do.

1. Add  the generic type contraint `new()` ensuring that the class has a parameter-less constructor and that you can call `new` on `T`.
2. Make the method generic.

```
public class GenericService
{
    public ReturnObject<T> GetResult<T>() 
        where T : new()
    {
        return new ResultService<T>().GetGoodResult(new T());
    }
}
```

If you don't want to create a new service each time, make the service a singleton

```
public class ResultService<T>
{
    public static readonly ResultService<T> Instance = new ResultService<T>();

    ...
}
```

The generic service becomes

```
public class GenericService
{
    public ReturnObject<T> GetResult<T>() 
        where T : new()
    {
        return ResultService<T>.Instance.GetGoodResult(new T());
    }
}
```